# Overwrite Blender python class method?

Tags: python, blender

Not sure what the right words are but,
I'm using Python to edit a 3d object in Blender. I can change the position by using:

```
some_3d_variable.obj.location = (0, 1, 0)
```

This moves the object to location (0, 1, 0) in meters i.e 100 centimeters:

[image]

I would like location to be in centimeters. Obviously i could write

```
some_3d_variable.obj.location = (0, 1/100,0)
```

[image]

But that's not a long term solution. But Can I do this under the hood?

I have a custom class the stores the `self.obj` that has the location method. The location method comes from Blender. But can I do some python magic such that `self.obj.position` divides the input with 100 but also set the 3d position in blender?

Here is an example. You can run this script in blender:

```
import bpy
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, KW_ONLY
import bmesh


@dataclass
class Sphere():
    def __post_init__(self):
        bm = bmesh.new()
        bmesh.ops.create_uvsphere(bm,u_segments=62, v_segments=36, radius=1)

        mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('Sphere')
        bm.to_mesh(mesh)
        mesh.update()
        bm.free()
        self.obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Sphere", mesh)
        bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(self.obj)
        
    # todo put here a method to handle obj.location, such that all the values are divided by 100 


s = Sphere()

# update position 
s.obj.location = (1, 0, 0)
```

This position is now set to 1 meter of the sphere object. I need to be 1/100 instead, i.e. a centimeters.. Any ideas?

Comment: it probably is doable using `@property` - but you have to add your code, in a complete, instalable way as a blender script so that people can build on it and test to help you.

Comment: thanks I provided an example